# Scrollable.ensureVisible(); not working if the widget is out of view?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, scrollview, global-key

I use `Scrollable.ensureVisible(GlobalObjectKey(category?.id).currentContext);` this code to scroll particular widget.

This is not working if the target widget is out of view.

For example I have a list 1 to 10. If I scroll 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 or 3 to 4 it's working smoothly. But if I go to `1 to 5` or `5 to 1` it's `not working`

And the code is,

```
return Container(
    key: GlobalObjectKey(category[index].id),
```

I use the below code to move to particular widget

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
Scrollable.ensureVisible(GlobalObjectKey(category?.id).currentContext);
```

Any help will be highly appriciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a ListView in flutter the index is only available for the visible widgets. A common solution would be to exchange ListView with

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(key: myKey, child: ...),
      ..all your widgets of your previous ListView
    ]

void scrollTo(GlobalKey itemKey) async {
  final context = itemKey.currentContext!;
  await Scrollable.ensureVisible(context);
}
```

now you can call scrollTo with your itemKey and the list will scroll to the respective item.